# How to SET DATEFIRST equal to Sunday in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

2016-01-01 is the week 1 of 2016, but also is the week 53 of 2015.

When I run `SELECT DATE_PART(w, '2016-01-01')` it returns `53`, but when I run `SELECT DATE_PART(w, '2016-01-04')` it returns `1`.

Most probably this is happening because Redshift sets Monday as the day 1 of the week, and not Sunday, as it should be.

Not sure if this will solve the problem, but what I need is to make 2016-01-01 as week 1 and from 2016-01-03 to 2016-01-09 as week 2 and so on...

Comment: What about 2015-12-31? Is it W53 or W1?

Comment: For 2015-12-31 it is W53.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom function with this case statement or use it in your SQL statements:

```
case when DATE_PART('W', dt)>=51 and EXTRACT(DOY FROM dt) < 8 then 1 else DATE_PART('W', dt)+1 end week_no
```

It will start counting weeks on Jan 1st.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ccb90/9

Comment: Additionally you can add `+ interval '1 day'` to the day_part functions to increment week number on sunday:

`case when DATE_PART('W', dt+ interval '1 day')>=51 and EXTRACT(DOY FROM dt) < 8 then 1 else DATE_PART('W', dt+ interval '1 day')+1 end week_no`

Comment: thank you for you reply. It seems to work pretty good! Saved the day!