# How to SET the last YEARWEEK to 53 in Amazon Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift

2015-12-27 is week 53 of 2015, but is also part of week 1 2016.

When I run DATE_PART('W', '2015-12-27' + interval '1 day') it returns 1, since 2016-01-01 is on Friday of that same week.

I have added the + interval '1 day', because I want the week to run from Sunday to Monday.

I am not sure how to set the final week of each year to 53, rather than 1 as is the case when the final week of a year shares days with the first week of the new year.  For example, I need 2015-12-27 to 2015-12-31 to be week 53 and 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-02 to be week 1.

Comment: See the simmilar answer [How to set 1/1 to Week 1 and 12/31 to Week 53](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416474/how-to-set-datefirst-equal-to-sunday-in-amazon-redshift/35418696#35418696)

Comment: I saw your answer there, but I still can't figure out the case statement needed to make the last week of the previous year 53 when the last week shares days with the first week of the new year.

Comment: I just figured it out (thanks vtuhtan):  CASE WHEN DATE_PART('DOY', ReturnDate) >= 358 AND DATE_PART('W', ReturnDate + interval '1 day') = 1
         THEN 53 
         ELSE DATE_PART('W', ReturnDate + interval '1 day') 
       END AS Week_Num

Comment: please write that as an answer so that it can be upvoted

Comment: @izzy84 you can accept the answer below

Answer (score 0):

See the simmilar answer [How to set 1/1 to Week 1 and 12/31 to Week 53](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35416474/how-to-set-datefirst-equal-to-sunday-in-amazon-redshift/35418696#35418696)

Create a custom function with this case statement or use it in your SQL statements:

```
CASE WHEN DATE_PART('DOY', ReturnDate) >= 358 AND DATE_PART('W', ReturnDate + interval '1 day') = 1 
    THEN 53 
    ELSE DATE_PART('W', ReturnDate + interval '1 day') 
END AS Week_Num
```